# Contact form doesn't work 2 errors

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

I have problem with contact form, don't send it. Unfortunately I'm not friendly with PHP  Bellow answer from my server provider.

> “Thank you for contacting us. I would like to inform you that the contact form shows the email address of the sender (should show up an email address created within the server home.pl): 
>   30.08.2014 12:49:26  [/usr/run/smtp] socket/plain(php5: xxxx.com/form/contact.php [1 work] DOCUMENT_ROOT=/ SCRIPT_FILENAME=/form/contact.php) [serwer111111] mess: e72823aae943c292 1108 from:  [magda.serwer111111] to:  [magda.serwer111111] status: LOCAL ERROR 554 5.7.1 Forged sender address:
>
> In addition, the administration of the default e-mail address field THIS: is supplemented by an invalid value (variable not substitute correct values):
>   30.08.2014 12:49:26  [/usr/run/smtp] socket/plain(php5: xxxx.com/form/contact.php [1 work] DOCUMENT_ROOT=/ SCRIPT_FILENAME=/form/contact.php) [serwer111111] mess: bf5e99f8a1316c4b 703 from:  [serwer111111] to:  [] status: REMOTE OK [0830124926_FE40E30F]

This is my contact form:

```
<?php

$receiving_email_address = "zydol@xxxx.com"; // Set your email address here which you want to receive emails to

$receiving_email_address_name = "Zydol"; // Add name that is associated with your email address above.

$custom_subject = "email from xxxx.com"; // Change the subject line of email as per your choice.

// ============================= DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE ======================================

if ((isset($_POST['name'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) > 0)) { $name = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['name'])); } else {$name = 'No name entered';}

if ((isset($_POST['phone'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['phone'])) > 0)) { $phone = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['phone'])); } else {$phone = 'No phone entered';}

if ((isset($_POST['email'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['email'])) > 0)) { $email = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['email'])); } else {$email = 'No email entered';}

if ((isset($_POST['datetimepicker'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['datetimepicker'])) > 0)) { $datetimepicker = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['datetimepicker'])); } else {$datetimepicker = 'No email entered';}

if ((isset($_POST['comment'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['comment'])) > 0)) { $comment = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['comment'])); } else {$phone = 'No comment entered';} ob_start();

// Email Building 
$to = $receiving_email_address; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$fromaddress = $_POST['email']; 
$fromname = $_POST['name']; 
$body = "Below are the details submitted by the user on your website.

Name: ".$_POST['name']."

Email: ".$_POST['email']."

Phone: ".$_POST['phone']."

Date & Time: ".$_POST['datetimepicker']."

Comment: ".$_POST['comment']."";

// Check if the security is filled 

if ( $_POST['security'] == '' ) {

    require("phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From                        = "$email";
    $mail->FromName            = "$fromname";
    $mail->AddAddress("$receiving_email_address","$receiving_email_address_name");

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject                 = "$custom_subject";
    $mail->Body                        = $body;
    $mail->AltBody                     = "This is the text-only body";

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $recipient                     = '$receiving_email_address';
        $subject                       = 'Contact form failed';
        $content                       = $body; 



  // Send Mail


mail($recipient, $subject, $content, "From: $receiving_email_address\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nX-Mailer: DT_formmail");
  exit;
}

} ?>
```

Can somebody help me?
Thank you in advance
Zydol

Answer (score 1):

The first message is because you ever set `$email`

add the line

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Comment: Can you tell me where I have to put the line?

Comment: @Zydol before `require("phpmailer.php");`

Comment: No I have it, some of code :                         `$to   = $receiving_email_address;`
`$email   = $_POST['email'];`
`$fromaddress  = $_POST['email'];`
`$fromname   = $_POST['name'];`

Comment: @zydol But it is commented out!

Comment: Ok, sorry my mistake, I just wrong copy code to post, now is ok. It isn't commented. Problem stil exist

Comment: Ok, I have it.Everything works nice